# Install4J Register Custom URI Mac

Tags: java, swing, installation, install4j

I have created a Java Swing based application that shows up a UI when executed and does some tasks through command line arguments and closes. I want to register custom URI for it so that when a URL like xxx://something is clicked in browser, my app opens up with in command line with URI passes as parameter.

For Windows I have achieved this by creating custom action to create required registry entries which uses JavaW.exe to launch my app with passes URI as parameter. This is working fine.

For Mac machines, I have added entries in info.plst, now this entry registers installed app with custom URI but the problem I am facing is that my executable JAR is not receiving URI as command line argument. Please let me know how to get this working with install4j (or any custom code if I may need to do in Java custom action).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install4j does not provide a facade to handle URI. You have to use the macOS-specific API in the JDK:

```
import com.apple.eawt.*;
...
Application.getApplication().setOpenURIHandler(new OpenURIHandler() {
    @Override
    public void openURI(AppEvent.OpenURIEvent openURIEvent) {
        URI uri = openURIEvent.getURI();
        //TODO handle uri
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ingo Kegel, since I am new to Java (as I work with c#) can you please point me to an example also please (if available).

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Hey Ingo Kegel, I had no luck getting this working in Mac. I have made my app single instance in install4j as per documentation. Does this method work with register URI approach? I am still getting no parameters since after opening a single instance, as soon as second link is clicked in browser with my custom URI... my app just comes into focus. Help!!!

Comment: This method just gives you the arguments from invocations of the executable. If your URI registration calls the executable again, you should receive the parameters.

Comment: Okay, the documentation says "This class allows you to register a listener to receive startup events in single instance mode on Microsoft Windows and file open events on macOS.". As per this it seems like it doesn't work with register URI approach, just file opens in Mac. Since app is being opened via URI and not by file opening. :( Please advise. I may be sounding silly but am stuck with it.

Comment: I was just wondering if their is some code I can write in custom action (maybe to change info.plst just after files are copied) so that instead of Executable Wrapper (generated by install4j) which gets triggered in Mac, my JAR gets triggered and is opened. Is it possible?

Comment: You are right, this only handles files, not URIs. I have edited my answer to provide the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ingo, your solution helped me in writing fix for my problem. Cheers J!

Comment: @RubalWalia, Hey Rubal, I am doing the same thing, can you provide a solution for MacOS?

Comment: My answer gave a solution for macOS.

Comment: @Marckaraujo, you will have to add custom entry in Info.plist file of the launcher for enabling the event listener. See XML sample below. <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Your App Name</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>prnbrg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>NSUIElement</key>
<true/>

Comment: @RubalWalia, yes, that I got. But how do you import the `import com.apple.eawt.*;`? Have you used the above code or found another way?

Comment: @Marckaraujo, if you are compiling under Mac then you won't have any compilation issues. In Windows machine you will have to add "OrangeExtendions" package. See link https://ymasory.github.io/OrangeExtensions/ for more details.